# URL pattern python Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am learning python django i am developing one website but i am struggling with URL pattern
I am Sharing my code for URL pattern i don't understand where i am getting wrong
url.py

```
urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^$',views.IndexView.as_view(),name='index'),

    # /music/id/
    url(r'^picture/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$',views.DetailView.as_view(),name='detail'),
    #for PictureDetail view
    url(r'^detail/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/(?P<alb_title>[\w%20+A-Za-z]+)/(?P<song_title>[\w%20+A-Za-z]+)$', views.PicturedetailView.as_view(), name='picturedetail'),

]
```

My Detail.html:-

```
 <ul>
         {% for picture in album.picture_set.all %}
          <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-2">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                            <a href="{% url 'music:picturedetail'  pk=picture.pk alb_title=picture.album.album_title song_title=picture.song_title  %}">
                                  <img src="{{ picture.file_type.url }}" class="img-responsive">
                            </a>
                            <div class="caption">
                              <h6>{{picture.song_title}}</h6>

                            </div>
                    </div>

            </div>

         {% endfor %}
      </ul>
{% endblock %}
```

I am passing three Parameters one with id and other two are strings ,i also updated my html href pattern but i am getting below error:-

```
Reverse for 'picturedetail' with keyword arguments '{'pk': 3, 'alb_title': 'Beautiful River', 'song_title': 'River'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['music/detail/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/(?P<alb_title>[\\w%20+A-Za-z]+)/(?P<song_title>[\\w%20+A-Za-z]+)$']
```

Thank you in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
url(r'^detail/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/(?P<alb_title>[\w\s+A-Za-z]+)/(?P<song_title>[\w\s+A-Za-z]+)$', views.PicturedetailView.as_view(), name='picturedetail'),
```

Answer (score 0):

"%20" is not what you want. Django sees the decoded URL, so you should use a space instead.